# Rename computer and join domain with one reboot in C#

Tags: c#, join, dns, rename

I'm trying to make a program that makes it easier for us to deploy new computers on the domain. What I want it to do, is simply rename the computer, and join it to our domain (it's going to be doing a lot of other stuff, but this isn't coming in till I've got this working).

Code here: http://pastebin.com/ayREYH0C

Stolen from http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Q_26262588.html and then changed to fit my needs

My problem is that the domain join doesn't respect the rename of the computer. I've put in a Thread.Sleep between the rename and the join so I had some time to check if the rename happens at all, and it does! When the domainjoin happens, it reverts back to the old name though and that is the computername that gets created in the domain, not the new name.

I've searched all around, but not found an issue like this, nor a solution for this particular need.

Comment: have you seen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217799/rename-computer-and-join-to-domain-in-one-step-with-powershell and http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ITCG/thread/ad11d4c0-20cd-406b-94a4-9551cdc73388/

Comment: also this may be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183759/programmatically-join-windows-machine-to-ad-domain

Comment: So the answer is: Join the domain, THEN change the name of the PC.
This presents a bit of a problem, since non-admins don't have permissions to change a computername, but I'll work around that, thanks alot for the help :)

Comment: no problem.. I just did some googling.. i was actually looking for some powershell script you could call but i found that instead.  If you get it figured out post and answer and accept it.. if its got any code I will upvote it ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a c# function that joins a workstation to a domain...thought you might find use of it as an alternate method that avoids WMI and uses ManagementObject instead:

(I realize that the executing credentials still need the rights to rename)

```
public static bool Join(string dom,string usr, string pass)
    {
        // Define constants used in the method.
        int JOIN_DOMAIN = 1;
        int ACCT_CREATE = 2;
        int ACCT_DELETE = 4;
        int WIN9X_UPGRADE = 16;
        int DOMAIN_JOIN_IF_JOINED = 32;
        int JOIN_UNSECURE = 64;
        int MACHINE_PASSWORD_PASSED = 128;
        int DEFERRED_SPN_SET = 256;
        int INSTALL_INVOCATION = 262144;

        // Define parameters that we will use later when we invoke the method.
        // Remember, the username must have permission to join the object in the AD.
        //string domain = "domain";
        //string password = "password";
        //string username = "username";
        //string destinationOU = "destinationOU";

        // Here we will set the parameters that we like using the logical OR operator.
        // If you want to create the account if it doesn't exist you should add " | ACCT_CREATE "
        // For more information see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392154%28VS.85%29.aspx
        int parameters = JOIN_DOMAIN | DOMAIN_JOIN_IF_JOINED;

        // The arguments are passed as an array of string objects in a specific order
        object[] methodArgs = { dom, pass, usr + "@" + dom, null, parameters };

        // Here we construct the ManagementObject and set Options
        ManagementObject computerSystem = new ManagementObject("Win32_ComputerSystem.Name='" + Environment.MachineName + "'");
        computerSystem.Scope.Options.Authentication = System.Management.AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy;
        computerSystem.Scope.Options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
        computerSystem.Scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true;

        // Here we invoke the method JoinDomainOrWorkgroup passing the parameters as the second parameter
        object Oresult = computerSystem.InvokeMethod("JoinDomainOrWorkgroup", methodArgs);

        // The result is returned as an object of type int, so we need to cast.
        int result = (int)Convert.ToInt32(Oresult);

        // If the result is 0 then the computer is joined.
        if (result == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Joined Successfully!");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            // Here are the list of possible errors
            string strErrorDescription = " ";
            switch (result)
            {
                case 5: strErrorDescription = "Access is denied";
                    break;
                case 87: strErrorDescription = "The parameter is incorrect";
                    break;
                case 110: strErrorDescription = "The system cannot open the specified object";
                    break;
                case 1323: strErrorDescription = "Unable to update the password";
                    break;
                case 1326: strErrorDescription = "Logon failure: unknown username or bad password";
                    break;
                case 1355: strErrorDescription = "The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted";
                    break;
                case 2224: strErrorDescription = "The account already exists";
                    break;
                case 2691: strErrorDescription = "The machine is already joined to the domain";
                    break;
                case 2692: strErrorDescription = "The machine is not currently joined to a domain";
                    break;
            }
            MessageBox.Show(strErrorDescription.ToString());
            return false;
        }

    }
```