# Issue while joining vm to a domain using invoke-vmscript

Tags: powershell, powercli, vcenter

I am trying to join a vm to a domain.  Here is the script:

```
Invoke-VMScript -vm $hostName -GuestUser $VMLocalUser -GuestPassword $VMLocalPWord -ScriptType Powershell "Add-Computer -ComputerName $hostName -LocalCredential $VMLocalCredential -DomainName $domainName -Credential $VMLocalCredential -Restart -Force"
```

While executing the script freezes at 0% completion.  Please let me know if am doing something wrong.

Comment: i even used below script to join but no luck

Comment: Invoke-VMScript -ScriptText 'netdom join %THE_COMPUTER_NAME% /domain:domin.COM /userd:administrator /passwordd:password' -Restart -Force

Comment: Are you able to verify that the script runs properly on the targeted machine without using Invoke-VMScript?  If so, are you able to verify that the script actually ran on the machine?  The issue I could see here is that potentially the computer reboots thus interrupting the Invoke-VMScript command.

Answer (score 0):

Running that add-computer command on the machine, I had trouble getting the ComputerName command to recognise which lead me to this

[Issue Adding PC to domain and changing name at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945551/issue-adding-pc-to-domain-and-changing-name-at-the-same-time)

Alternatively use netdom.

Invoke-VMScript -VM $vmname -GuestUser $VMLocalUser -GuestPassword $VMLocalPWord  -ScriptType Powershell "netdom join /d:mywork.domain computername /userd:domainaccount /passwordd:pwd"